# Twitter session not destroying when the user logout from the Myapp

Tags: php, session, twitter, logout

I'm using OAuth in my web app, and users can connect with twitter.But when user is disconnect account which remove the session and open log in window again for user.

I destroy session in my app but it does not log out from twitter account.
When user log in again then it is automatically authenticate the previous log in account.

i changed code in twitter/twitteroauth.php

```
          function getAuthorizeURL($token, $sign_in_with_twitter = TRUE) {
        if (is_array($token)) {
          $token = $token['oauth_token'];
        }
        if (empty($sign_in_with_twitter)) {
          return $this->authorizeURL() . "?oauth_token={$token}";
        } else {
           return $this->authorizeURL() . "?oauth_token={$token}&force_login=false"; 

        }
      }
```

and on logout page i wrote:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['TWITTER_status'])){
            session_destroy();
            unset( $_SESSION['TWITTER_status']);
            header('Location:connect.php');  
        }
```

How can i destroy session of twitter completely So user can switch account easily?

Comment: As far as I know, OAuth remembers and links between your site/app to the Twitter account. twitter-bootstrap tag is irrelevant; please remove that.

Comment: You cannot logout the user from OAuth provider. That has to be done manually by the user. All you can do is manage the session  state in your app and redirect to Authentication after logout. If the user is already logged in on the system/browser and permission was provided then the OAuth provider page will take that for a valid login.

Comment: Thanks.Can you give some code example?